# React/Enzyme Unit Test Async/Await Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, enzyme

I've been tasked with updating an existing component to make validation calls to a server-side implementation.  So I converted a few calls in a react component to be `async` functions.

**Problem Statement** Getting access to a `ref` and/or `this` in the React component is not working in my test, and I am having difficulty determining why.

ES6/React class with manual bind for formatPhoneNumber

```
class PhoneView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // note the manual bind here instead of using arrow function
        this.formatPhoneNumber = this.formatPhoneNumber.bind(this);
```

**ref code snip from render() method**

```
<div className="position-relative">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" defaultValue={this.getPhoneValue()}
    data-prop="phone"
    data-countrycode={this.state.activeCountryCode}
    className="phone js-phone form-control no-border-radius-left"
    ref={
    (jsPhone) => {
    this.jsPhone = jsPhone;
   }
  }
    onBlur={this.formatPhoneNumber}
    onInput={this.adjustInputPadding}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onKeyUp={this.removeError}
    data-at-id="phone"
    data-tracking-label="phone"
    autoComplete="off"
    style={{ paddingLeft: this.state.inputPaddingLeft }}
/>
```

**Async code (under test)**- `this` is undefined, so access to property set by `ref` is not possible during the test.

```
async formatPhoneNumber() {

    try {
      let valid;
       const phoneNumberValue = this.jsPhone.value.trim();  // this is undefined here during test
       ...
```

**Test code snippet**

```
describe('phone view', () => {
    let wrapper;
    let instance;
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = Enzyme.mount(
            <PhoneView/>);
            instance = wrapper.instance();
    });
```

// .....

```
describe('#formatPhoneNumber', () => {
        it.only('should format the phone number', async() => {
            const phoneInput = wrapper.find('.js-phone');
            phoneInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: '+14152223333' } });
            const foo = await instance.formatPhoneNumber();
            // make some expectations
        });
    });
```

**Question:**
Is there a "best/better" way to test `async` functions for a React component using enzyme, especially when `refs` are used?

Comment: there could be something else. when i tried to run your code. i am not getting this undefined.

Comment: Just checked the similar test case and it works! check, please, what is in `foo` variable?
immediately, after getting value of `await instance.formatPhoneNumber();`, you can check it in `expect` expression.

Comment: I changed the formatPhoneNumber to an arrow function and it works, but manually binding in the constructor, in my case, causes `this` to be undefined...  Will try again and get back.